# Parametric Equation of sine wave wrapped around a cylinder

Tags: parametric, curves, parametrization

Hello i have a 2 axis machine [my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axmuA.png) with Z (linear axis) and C (rotation axis) 
So what i want is an equation for each axis so that they can produce a profile of [sine wave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjViI.png) around the cylinder with some variables like the (d)diameter of the cylinder ,(n)number of positive half cycles and negative half cycles and (a)the amplitude (i guess it will be a function of d and n)

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by number of sine waves (x) ?

Comment: number of positive half cycles plus negative half cycles.
as the sine wave contains one positive half cycle and one negative half cycle.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Not sure but the "number of sine waves" is probably the number of maxima (or minima) in some fixed interval, i.e. the frequency of the wave, and $x$ is the notation for it, i.e. the wave is $a \sin x$. What the OP ignores is the fact that a differentiable curve "wrapped" around a surface will have *one*, not two parameters, by its very nature of being a curve.

Comment: This parameter, surely common in electrical engineering is uncommon, I think, for most of us. It would be better to speak in terms of frequency or pulsation of the sine wave.

Comment: I need to wrap a sine wave and control it so that i can get different shapes on the same cylinder and/or by getting the same shape on different cylinder sizes

[link](https://s28.postimg.org/tk6q4kzgt/asd.png)
[link](https://s28.postimg.org/ozkjpnfrh/image.png)

Comment: You needed to edit your question.. maybe it would fetch better answers. Only after some guesses and comments there was some clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand what you mean by number of sine waves.

For a single sine wave wrapped around a cylinder radius $a$, its amplitude $A$ axis coinciding with cylinder generator we have

$$ (x,y,z)= ( a \cos  \theta, a \sin \theta, A \cos \theta)$$

EDIT 1:

$$ \Delta z -A \sin \theta \omega$$

which can be converted to vertical feed rate and center cylinder angular velocity

where $\theta$ is polar angle. It has an ellipse for its boundary obtained by intersection of a slanted plane inclined at $ \tan^{-1}(A/a)$ to plane of circumference.

To pack in more $(=n) $ waves we have

$$ (x,y,z)= ( a \cos  \theta, a \sin  \theta, A \cos n \theta)$$

[image]

Comment: I need to wrap a sine wave and control it so that i can get different shapes on the same cylinder and/or by getting the same shape on different cylinder sizes

[link](https://s28.postimg.org/tk6q4kzgt/asd.png)
[link](https://s28.postimg.org/ozkjpnfrh/image.png)

Comment: The link figure you gave as above is for n=2 waves

Comment: yes that's it , but how to determine a point as a form of z direction(how mm) and in C direction (how degree)

Comment: i have a machine with two axis Z and rotation along z(C axis ) so i want two equations so that these two axes can follow it

Comment: Since helix angle changes, no constant feed rates  for $ r, \theta$ can be given. Is it a CNC milling machine? Lathe?

Comment: No changes in helix angles , yes it is similar in concept

Comment: The black cylinder is supposed to represent an end mill cutter? If so, your question is already answered.